# Possible to use PEAR SearchReplace to replace text within a .php file?

Tags: php, pear, replace

I came across this simple pear tutorial over here: http://www.codediesel.com/php/search-replace-in-files-using-php/

```
include 'File/SearchReplace.php' ;

$files_to_search = array("fruits.txt") ;
$search_string  = "apples";
$replace_string = "oranges";

$snr = new File_SearchReplace($search_string,
                          $replace_string,
                          $files_to_search,
                          '', // directorie(s) to search
                          false) ;

$snr->doSearch();

echo "The number of replaces done : " . $snr->getNumOccurences();
```

The writer uses the fruits.txt file as an example.

I would like to do a search and replace on a .php file.

Basically what I am trying to achieve would be this:

On a user interaction, index.php is opened,

`$promoChange = "%VARYINGTEXT%";`

is searched for and replaced with

`$promoChange = "$currentYear/$currentPromotion";`

The `$current` variables will vary, hence the need to change the words inbetween the `""` only.

Does anyone have any input on how this type of task could be accomplished?

If anyone knows of any tutorials relating to this subject, that too would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

- I do have everything else figured out, regarding the template and user interaction, I am just having trouble trying to work out how to accomplish this type of search and replace. I have an understand of how it should be done as I have made something similiar using visual basic. But I am starting to this that my answer for this would be perl? I hope that this is not so...

Okay, my problem is partly solved with this:

```
// Define result of Activate click
if (isset($_POST['action']) and $_POST['action'] == 'Activate')
{   
include ''.$docRoot.'/includes/pear/SearchReplace.php' ;
$files = array( "$docRoot/promotions/index.php" ) ;
$snr = new File_SearchReplace( '$promoChange = "";', '$promoChange = "'.$currentYear.'/'.$currentPromotion.'";', $files) ;
$snr -> doSearch() ;
}
```

but how do i get it to search and replace something like $promoChange = `"%VARYINGTEXT%";`

It found and replaced "" with the current session values. But now that is has changed, I need it to replace and text inbetween "AND".

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: Why don't you just replace it? Should be no problem at all.

Comment: What doesn't work with that script you found? Have you replaced the filename and search and replacment text snippets with what you want? What was the outcome?

Comment: @mario @hakre Well, it does not alter the index.php file that I have assigned to `$files_to_search` so I thought that maybe this was a .txt only function.

Comment: @mario Please see update to my op

Comment: @hakre Please see update to my op

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need to adapt a single file, then do it manually:

```
$src = file_get_contents($fn = "script.php");
$src = str_replace('"%VARYINGTEXT%"', '"$currentYear/$currentPromotion"', $src);
file_put_contents($fn, $src);
```

`str_replace` is sufficient for your case.

Comment: Thank you so much!! That is a very clean and simple approach. It works quickly too. But, once `"%VARYINGTEXT%"` has been changed, how would i replace this new text it creates? How would I make it so that no matter what is inbetween "" it will always replace it with the replacement variables?

Comment: `$src = preg_replace('/\$xyz = ".*?"/', '$xyz = "new"', $src);`

Comment: Thank you so much for all of the help! this has solved my problem beyond my expectations. The correct regex though, was this [^"]* I did try your one first, but did not produce the desired result. But as for the nay sayer below this, do you know why they imply that what I have just done should not be done?

Comment: You haven't explained your use case. -- Modifying source code is always a fiddly task. And it needs a more stringent regex actually. (Using something similar, but it's more well-constrained.)

Answer (score 0):

Why on earth do you want to do something like that? Frameworks like PHP do exist solely on the base of not having to write a page for each different view of the same interaction. What's wrong with just including the PHP page you now want to change, and set the variables accordingly before calling it?

Ontopic: I don't see why what you're doing is a problem, purely technically speaking. This can be done using PHP. But really, you shouldn't.

Comment: I would like to do this, because it is part of a cms application that controls promotions that are displayed on a website. I would like the user to be able to upload a set of images to the relevant folder, then activate this "promotion" which is then displayed live in the promotions section of the website. Technically speaking though, i could simply change the variables and include the page. But i need a simple process to enable the rest of the world to see that included page, until it is changed again. The people i am working with have no clue about html, let alone ftp.

Comment: I am trying to alter the file location of the two .jpg files that make up the promotion, that are within the index.php file that is displayed live.